# C# winform picturebox image lost after saving data

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, picturebox

I have a winform application in which there is a pictureBox what displays a pretty big image (2550by4500). This bitmap image is transformed from a byte array using unsafe pointer, like this:

```
     Bitmap img;   
     unsafe
     {
         fixed (Byte* intPtr = &outBuffer[0])
         img = new Bitmap(_width, _height, _width * 3, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(intPtr));
     }
```

So far, no problems. After displaying the image, I saved the pixel values into a Matlab .mat file using this DLL (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319). Still, no problem with saving.

However, the image in the pictureBox became like a noisy black-white image, the original image was completely lost.

Things I tried:

1. added the Bitmap in watch window, found out pixel values all changed. Bitmap is corrupted.
2. do that unsafe transformation again everytime after saving, however, it brings another problem: "AccessViolationException in Drawing.dll".

Something must have to do with the .mat saving part, because if I skip saving, no problem at all. But I do not know how they are related, memory? I tried a smaller size image, no problem. so I'm assuming that "save .mat" process corrupted the Bitmap?

Any idea would be helpful! Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this, the pointer in no longer valid after the fixed statement.  The next garbage collection completely scrambles the bitmap, the AccessViolation is the expected outcome.

Comment: thanks for you quick reply. Is there a way I can keep the image in pictureBox without losing it? prevent it from GC

Comment: PictureBox never has a problem displaying its Image property.  Unless you intentionally corrupt it like you did.  Don't corrupt it.

Comment: thank you so much. Guess I'll have to not to display the images after the ".mat saving".